# Prefixing all text-code symbols in a `.o` file

Tags: linker, fortran, static-libraries, ffi

I have multiple Fortran static libraries which have functions with the same name, that I'd like to call from Rust. Using `objcopy` prefixing, I can make the names unique, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393980/restricting-symbols-in-a-linux-static-library):

```sh
ld -r obj1.o obj2.o ... objn.o -o static1.o
objcopy --localize-hidden --prefix-symbols=foo static1.o static2.o
ar -rcs mylib.a static2.o
```

However, it seems that `objcopy` prefixes *all* symbols, even the ones that only appear as a function call to an external library. Thus, I get errors such as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xaf0c): undefined reference to `foo_gfortran_runtime_error_at'
```

It seem then that I only want to rename the symbols that are marked as `T` in `nm`. Is this correct? Is there a way to do this with `objcopy` or `ld`?

Do you also know of a solution that works on Mac as well (where `objcopy` is unavailable)?

Comment: It would be easier to wrap the code for each static library in a module with a unique name.  Fortran compilers typically mangle the names of entities within a module.  For example, my Gaussian elimination routines are wrapped in module named gaussm, and the double precision function gauss_dble has the name __gaussm_MOD_gauss_dble in the library.